# Iterating over a nested json field in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, json, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to iterate over a field in pyspark dataframe which is in json format. In some cases it can be empty like this '[]' and other may have a nested structure. Can someone please help me out on how can I iterate over the column given the condition that I only want the rows that aren't empty and rather having values. Also I want to fetch specific fields from it.
[Structure of the json field dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/If3cK.png)

I tried to iterate over the column using collect function. But this was helpful only when the field was having empty values. This is the code.
`

```
data = []
columns = ['created_date','description','id','last_modified_date','links','name','order','parent_id','pid','recursive','project_id']
for i in landing_df.collect():
  
  if(len(i["children"]) == 0):
    data.append([i["created_date"],i["description"],i["id"],i["last_modified_date"],i["links"],i["name"],i["order"],-1,i["pid"],i["recursive"],i["project_id"]])
#     if(landing_df.shared):
#       sourceDF.shared = landing_df.shared
    
    print(i["id"])

sourceDF1 = spark.createDataFrame(data,columns)
```

`

I want to fetch the data from the children field and append it to the data variable just like I did it above.